# How to invert a CGFloat in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, cgfloat

I have a `CGFloat` `a` and need a `CGFloat` `b`, inverted from a.

If `a` is 0, I need `b` to be 100. If `a` is 1, I need `b` to be 99 ans so on.

The only solution I came up with right now is a function like the following:

```
func turn(_ a: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    switch a {
    case 0:
        return 100
    case 1:
        return 99
    case 2:
        return 98
    case 3:
        return 97
    case 4:
        return 96
    case 5:
        return 95
    case 6:
        return 94
    case 7:
        return 93
    case 8:
        return 92
    case 9:
        return 91
    case 10:
        return 90
```

But a) is that insane to write for 100 Floats, and b), I need it for an animation and I receive `a` in `UITableView.offset` Floats, so the steps are with x decimal places and therefore I want `b` to be in decimal steps as well (to have the animation smooth).

Any ideas? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: This is a trivial math problem as seen by Nirav's answer.

Comment: what can i say. i have been thinking about that for 2 hours now and i did not came up with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply like this.

```
let invert: CGFloat = 100
let a: CGFloat = 0
let b = invert - a
```

**Or Simply**

```
let b = 100 - a
```

Comment: that's pretty embarrassing... 2 hours on that and i came not up with the easiest math... thank you